# cakephp $this->redirect not working in function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to cake and I'm trying to get the function to redirect after an event has been saved.. it works in other code e.g. users, but not in the events one..

THE FUNCTION DOES SAVE THE EVENT, ITS JUST IT WONT REDIRECT OR USE THE SETFLASH

Here is the code for my event controller add funciton:

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Event->create();
            if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'eventmanage'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be saved. Please, contact the administrator.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: The most probable cause is that your application is outputting some data *before* the redirect headers are sent. Check if there is a space before your `<?php` tag, or after the `?>` closing tag (you should remove those anyway in php-only files) if your file contains a utf-8 BOM, etc. You may be able to check this by inspecting the response inside firebug or Chrome webinspector

Comment: Thanks, you can post it as an answer if you want as the whole `<?php ?>` was the problem.. 

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable cause is that your application is outputting some data before the redirect headers are sent.

Check if there is a space before your `<?php` tag, or after the `?>` closing tag (you should remove those anyway in php-only files), or if your file contains a utf-8 BOM, etc.

You may be able to check this by inspecting the response inside firebug or Chrome webinspector

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a comment, but couldn't yet.

If you are wondering which is the file that is outputting that data that is preventing the redirect you must be very thorough.

In my case was something as aparently inocent as a comment (html comment) that I put in the **MODEL** from which view I wanted to redirect (not so obvious to find).
This blank page not redirected could be as simple as a **line feed** or and **space** just before the `<?php ?>` both VERY hard to find, and both would prevent redirection.

If you are having this problem hope my hints help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in before filter function

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); // // HTTP/1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
```